# Auto sorted list c# with duplicate keys

Tags: c#

I have a series of objects and a function

```
double P(Object a, Object b){...}
```

Now, for a fixed Object a, I would like to store inside a list L all the other objects in this way:

```
Objects a,b,c,d with P(a,b)=1, P(a,c)=2, P(a,d)=1 should have

L[0] = b or d, L[1] = b or d, L[2] = c
```

Note that I only need to access (not modify, delete ecc..) the items stored in L, if L could be a SortedList then IndexOfValue would be perfect but it doesn't support duplicate keys.

Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you trying to do a `GroupBy`?

Comment: `SortedDictionary<K, List<V>>` where `K` and `V` are key and value types

Comment: @DmitryBychenko so is he grouping by `P(o1,o2)`?

Comment: @dcg: "Auto sorted list c# with duplicate keys" - `SortedDictionary<K,List<V>>`; adding can be `if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out var list)) list.Add(value); else dict.Add(key, new List<int>() { value });`

Answer (score 0):

From the c# interactive shell

```cs
// making up a class, since there aren't any details.
// make it have some kind of value, and a human friendly name
public class Thing { public int Val {get; set;} public string Name { get; set; } }

// since P isn't given, make something up. How about adding two numbers?
Func<Thing, Thing, double> P = (a, b) => { return a.Val + b.Val; };

// give starting values to match example function output
var a = new Thing() { Val = 0, Name = "a" };
var b = new Thing() { Val = 1, Name = "b" };
var c = new Thing() { Val = 2, Name = "c" };
var d = new Thing() { Val = 1, Name = "d" };

// others is the list of values, sorted by the output from the function "P",
// compared against the first Thing ("a" in this case")
var others = (new List<Thing>() { b,c,d }).OrderBy(x => P(a, x));

// interactive shell out gives:
```

---

```
. others.Select(x => x.Name)
Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<Submission#0.Thing, string> { "b", "d", "c" }
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for but your example is not correct: b, c, d should have Val = P(a, b or c or d) and then I should order others by the value stored in Val for each element that I added to others